# JavaScript defining variable issue

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to declare a new audio element in JavaScript. This is what I have written.

```
//Creating audio object
var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
audio.src = '/beats/vibe/lofi2.wav';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = false;
audio.autoplay = false;
```

I am receiving the following error:
'document' is not definded [no-undef]

Any clues as to why this wont work? Thanks!

Comment: where and when do you get this error ? looks like a linting error, not a browser error

Comment: That sounds like an eslint error. You'll need to tell it you're writing for web (if that's what you're doing)

Comment: It is an eslint error, and yes I am developing for web. Sorry wasn't aware that changed anything. Neither of the below solutions fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.document`. Replace

```
var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
```

with

```
var audio = window.document.createElement("AUDIO");
```

Or in some cases we can also include `/*global document require*/` on top of the script files. This will ensure that `document` is available for the script.

Comment: This just moved the error to window. How would I implement that second solution?

Answer (score 0):

The object must be inserted into DOM. After crafting your audio tag, use:

```
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

### Demo

```js
var audio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
audio.src = 'https://vocaroo.com/media_command.php?media=s1XsCD8OHZPI&command=download_mp3'
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = false;
audio.autoplay = false;
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with an external JavaScript file?

Comment: @CalebSmith Yes, sir

Comment: @CalebSmith `{ "env": { "browser": true } }` in your `.eslintrc` file. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841893/2813224)

Comment: Would I just add the .eslintrc file to the folder? Do I need to reference it in any way in my HTML or JavaScript file?

Comment: No problem, sir. To summarize, it was an eslint problem but keep in mind that your code will run in a browser (as long as you add the tag to DOM ex.`document.body.appendChild(audio);`)